# fastest way to apply an async function to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-asyncio

There is an `apply` method in pandas dataframe that allows to apply some sync functions like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def fun(x):
    return x * 2

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['old'])

df['new'] = df['old'].apply(fun)
```

What is the fastest way to do similar thing if there is an async function `fun2` that has to be applied:

```
import asyncio
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

async def fun2(x):
    return x * 2

async def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['old'])
    df['new'] = 0    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df['new'].iloc[i] = await fun2(df['old'].iloc[i])
    print(df)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) and overwrite the whole column when complete.

```
import asyncio

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


async def fun2(x):
    return x * 2


async def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10), columns=['old'])
    df['new'] = await asyncio.gather(*(fun2(v) for v in df['old']))
    print(df)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Doing it this way will pass each value in the column to the async function, meaning that all column values will be being run concurrently (which will be much faster than awaiting each function result sequentially in a loop).

Note: Column order is guaranteed to be preserved by [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) and the column will not be resolved until all awaitables have successfully completed.

Resulting output DataFrame:

```
   old  new
0    0    0
1    1    2
2    2    4
3    3    6
4    4    8
5    5   10
6    6   12
7    7   14
8    8   16
9    9   18
```

Comment: How do we make the output into a pandas dataframe ?

Comment: @snow the output is a list of the results of `fun2()` over the `df['old']` Series. @Henry's answer just assigns that list to a new column (Series) in the original `df`

Comment: One of the most ingenious ways to mix pandas with asyncio I've seen. Actually had to hunt for it in my browser's history. LOL

Comment: Will the correct order of the elements always be preserved?

Comment: @BulatIbragimov Yes. From the linked gather docs: "The order of result values corresponds to the order of awaitables in _aws_."