# How to write the division of two columns of a dataframe using asyncio?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

```
def divis(data):
    data['prom'] = data['total']/data['num2']
    return data
```

```
async def divis(data):
    data['prom'] = await (data['total']/data['num2'])
    return data
await divis(df2)
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

Comment: Pandas doesn't support asynchronous operations. You have to write the "data['prom'] =..." line in the same way as for the synchronous function.

Comment: thanks look, I want to do something like this, but dividing two columns of the dataframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944791/fastest-way-to-apply-an-async-function-to-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question [fastest way to apply an async function to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944791/fastest-way-to-apply-an-async-function-to-pandas-dataframe) and its accepted answer, this will look like:

```
import asyncio

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

async def fun2(x, y):
    return x / y

async def divis(data):
    data['prom'] = await asyncio.gather(*(fun2(x, y) for x, y in zip(data['total'], data['num2'])))
    return data
 
await divis(df2)
```