# Fill Pandas Dataframe asynchronously with async

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-asyncio

I just saw [this awesome video from Idently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8tnmEdeOU0) and tried to use the trick to fill in some dataframe columns according to another.

Here is my MWE (more like non-working example infact) code, I code in a Jupyter notebook.

```py
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import requests

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'url':['https://google.com','https://apple.com']})
print(mydf)
print("-----")

async def fetch_status(url:str) -> int:
    response = await asyncio.to_thread(requests.get,url)
    return(response.status_code)

async def main_task() -> None:
    myTask = asyncio.create_task(mydf['url'].apply(fetch_status))
    mydf['status'] = await myTask
   
    print(mydf)
```

In a separate cell:

```py
asyncio.run(main = main_task())
```

I get a `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` error.
Any idea why? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split and fix your code like so:

Cell 1:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import Task
import pandas as pd
import requests

mydf = pd.DataFrame({'url':['http://google.com','http://apple.com']})
print(mydf)

async def fetch_status(url:str) -> int:
    response = await asyncio.to_thread(requests.get,url,None)
    return(response.status_code)

async def main_task() -> None:
    mydf['status'] = await asyncio.gather(*[fetch_status(url) for url in mydf['url']])
```

Cell 2:

```
await main_task()
```

Comment: Thanks! After further lookup I found that exact answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944791/fastest-way-to-apply-an-async-function-to-pandas-dataframe. Thanks for your help. BTW are you the guy behind the YT channel? I think he's named Frederico as well.

Comment: Ahhah no, I'm not